# What's the cause of double fault on CPU

Tags: interrupts, machine-check-exception

It's my assumption right, if I say that double fault can and must occurs only in processor's kernel mode (or ring 0 for x86) when any exception (synchronous) happens and never else?

If answer is yes, in newer processors that are compatible with older ones, we can't use in code, that runs in kernel mode, already defined instructions (in newer CPU) if we want to preserve this compatibility in the reason of undefined instruction exception, is it right? And other one question. If CPU executes a code that runs in kernel mode, it must be presented in memory in the reason of page fault, isn't it so?

And my additional thought. Are there any benefits from that it will be implemented "internal INT enable bit" in status register that will be automatically sets and clears on interrupt/exception occurs and its return and if exception happens HW reads this bit and if is set, it jumps to exception handler address, otherwise ir jumps to double fault handler?

If it is architecture/OS dependent, I choose Linux on MIPS.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: I recommend we send your question over to StackOverflow. Your question has a lot to do with hardware, but there are very very few assembler programmers or kernel hackers here, and this is a little over my head. Good luck to you.

Comment: They will reject that migration....

Comment: There isn't code, nor a request for it, why is it not on topic here?

Comment: Given that there seems to be 4 questions in there, I'm voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 3):

I have a lot of experience with the x86, but nothing on MIPS, sorry - but I believe that the following description applies for it anyway.

A Double Fault **only** occurs in a very particular circumstance: If, while attempting to **start** an exception handler, another exception occurs, then the first exception is abandoned and the Double Fault exception handler is called instead.

Here is an example of a simple fault. If code attempts to access invalid memory:

```
*(int *)0 = 0xdead;
```

then the CPU will detect the NULL pointer reference and try to start the Memory fault handler. This could be in User (ring 3) or Supervisor (ring 0) code, and no Double Fault would occur - the CPU would simply try to start the Memory fault handler.

Imagine though that the OS had a bug and the Memory fault handler *itself* was in invalid memory. Thus, while trying to **start** the Memory fault handler, another fault happened and the first fault couldn't be handled. The Double Fault handler would then be called. (If a fault occurs while trying to **start** the Double Fault handler, the x86 CPU simply shuts down with a Triple Fault. The PC hardware detects this and resets the CPU.)

I have repeatedly emphasised **start** because once a fault handler has **started** successfully, no Double Fault will occur anymore. The first fault has started being handled, and the CPU can now handle any new faults that may come along. The CPU doesn't "remember" that it is inside a fault handler and cause a Double Fault if a new fault happens.

Per your example, if a fault handler attempts to use an undefined opcode, then the Undefined Opcode fault handler would simply be called on that instruction. It is not a Double Fault, it is merely a fault within a fault.

Of course, if the Memory fault handler starts, and while processing it causes a Memory fault, then the Memory fault handler will be restarted. That might cause the same Memory fault again, which will restart the Memory fault handler - each time using more and more stack until finally the stack itself overflows, which on the x86 is a different fault handler.

Comment: And finally, when stack overflow happens on an attempt to invoke memory fault handler, you'll get your Double Fault.

Comment: It is important to emphasise start. It's literally when a fault occurs during the MSROM microcode routine that is starting up the call to the OS handler, not during the OS handler itself

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I can give you, is that yes, it is correct that with most modern CPUs only code running in Kernel mode can trigger a [double or triple fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_fault). It is very rare (but not impossible) for a non-kernel initiated instruction to trigger a hard fault, due to ProtectedMode operation, which abstracts away physical addressing such that its no longer possible to branch into an invalid register address.

As such, yes, any machine code assembled for a CPU without [ProtectedMode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode) should be at least reassembled, if not modified, to work on a newer CPU.

From Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode#Virtual_8086_mode

> Virtual 8086 mode Main article: Virtual 8086 mode
>
> With the release of the 386, protected mode offers what the Intel
>   manuals call virtual 8086 mode. Virtual 8086 mode is designed to allow
>   code previously written for the 8086 to run unmodified and
>   concurrently with other tasks, without compromising security or system
>   stability.[29]
>
> Virtual 8086 mode, however, is not completely backwards compatible
>   with all programs. Programs that require segment manipulation,
>   privileged instructions, direct hardware access, or use self-modifying
>   code will generate an exception that must be served by the operating
>   system.[30] In addition, applications running in virtual 8086 mode
>   generate a trap with the use of instructions that involve input/output
>   (I/O), which can negatively impact performance.[31]
>
> Due to these limitations, some programs originally designed to run on
>   the 8086 cannot be run in virtual 8086 mode. As a result, system
>   software is forced to either compromise system security or backwards
>   compatibility when dealing with legacy software. An example of such a
>   compromise can be seen with the release of Windows NT, which dropped
>   backwards compatibility for "ill-behaved" DOS applications.[32]

I hope that helps a little, and that if it is insufficient, that another can fill in any gaps in my understanding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but sorry, it wasn't answered my questions. With newer CPU, I didn't mean transition between processor that operates on real addresses and the one that operates on virtual addresses. I meant if successor of some CPU (both support virtual addressing with some protection and are fully forward compatible) added some new instruction, if this instruction can be used in kernel mode of a software that will be running on both of these CPUs. In this case, CPU in kernel mode would invoke double fault on older CPU, because of undefined instruction exception, isn't it true?

Comment: An undefined instruction exception will cause a double/triple fault iff it is the instruction indicated in an interrupt or exception routine. if it is in normal code however, it should not. the fault will occur, and the branch into exception handling should occur as normal. I'm not quite seeing where protected or kernel mode come into it though. Are you planning to run some code as kernel to get around protected mode compability and asking if this approach might cause issues? because yes, it could. will it? depends on the code and the hardware.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No this isn't my plan. So, you want to tell me, when "normal" code is running in kernel mode, exception doesn't occur direct invoke double fault handler, but it invokes appropriate exception handler? If so, then where is the difference between "normal" code and interrupt handler code and how CPU knows what exception handler should invokes? (meaning any exception handler vs double fault handler)

Comment: a double fault happens when there is one fault, and then when the CPU attempts to handle it, another fault occurs, within the handler. double faults can only happen in handler code. so, is the instruction in question part of an exception/interrupt handler? if it is, it can cause a double fault. if not, it can't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By you, kernel thread can normally causes exceptions? (not meaning programmer mistakes, but for example already mentioned undefined instruction, maybe page faults (swapped out if it is possible for kernel thread)) It has some logic, but how CPU recognize if this is interrupt/exception handler, not kernel thread that causes exception (both running in CPU kernel mode) ?

Comment: that's beyond me. I know that most CPUs have an interrupt register, which stores vectors of addresses containig instructions to fire in the case of the interrupt, but I don;t know what puts the instructions in those addresses, or how the instructions are defined.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your time, but I can't accept your answer, because it doesn't directly answers my question. But this discussing was very useful for me.